# Why one page can make whole computer freeze?

Tags: google-chrome, windows

Sometimes when I load pages (*) in chrome the whole computer freeze for a minute. Why it is happening? What I can do to avoid it?

(*) For example this one http://www.nerfnow.com/

Comment: Problem is that is not happening every time. Not every time when it happened it makes CPU usage in history go to 100% .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome is running each time in separate process so the CPU consumption can reach 100% even if you have multi-core CPU. So you should check the CPU consumption for Chrome processes in Process exporer.

What can freeze computer totally is however the heavy disc consumption. If the site is heavy, a lot of memory is allocated, that can cause heavy page swapping, causing the freeze of the whole operating system. Watch the disc usage (modern silent discs make it, however, harder).

Answer (score 3):

If your browser (more specifically, your CPU) is left to do a lot of processing then it would become slow. Usually poorly written or long running JavaScript are the cause.

I tried opening the site you mentioned in your question but the site didn't made my browser run slow, it was all fine, looks like you have some other problem either with your PC hardware or/and software configurations. Check for suspicious software installed on your PC and also extensions added in your browser, it might be the cause for this.