# Pages in Chrome with lots of HTML elements make the whole computer unresponsive for minutes at a time

Tags: windows, google-chrome, freeze

I have an annoying problem for a long time now and I was unable to find the root cause.

When some page with a lot of HTML elements (especially tables with many rows and columns) renders in Chrome, it can make my whole machine unresponsive for several minutes. For example, this happens often when I open the page https://instances.vantage.sh. It also happens (for a few seconds only, but still) every time I expand or collapse a tree node in a large CPU profile loaded into DevTools, or when I open a huge page like https://tc39.es/ecma262/ (the ECMAScript spec document). Most interestingly, this happens *after* it seemingly already loaded, and I was even able to scroll around for a second or two.

The most peculiar thing here is the *way* in which the computer becomes unresponsive. It's not like any other kind of high-load situation I usually encounter. It seems that pretty much every software that tries to render *anything* gets stuck or slowed down with delays of tens of seconds, including the seconds shown in my taskbar clock. *My mouse cursor becomes slow to respond* and seems to update its position only 1-2 times per second. The Chrome window itself gets a native titlebar with "(not responding)" and a white overlay during that time. When I look at task manager or Process Hacker (provided it was open before, because I can't open it during that time) then it also freezes during the problematic time, but looking at the load history graphs after it unfroze, I can see that the only thing out of the ordinary was that during that time the Chrome process corresponding to the problematic tab used one full CPU core but *almost fully in kernel mode*. So, whatever activity is happening in the kernel at that time must have this strange system-wide effect! Note that the other CPU cores are not loaded, there is plenty of RAM available and the GPU is also not showing any more load than normally.

Do you have any clue what could cause this? It can't be normal that a webpage can essentially DoS my whole computer. How would I go about debugging this further? Normally I'd look at the stack of the thread using that CPU in kernel mode while it's happening but I can't do that because I can't operate any other application like Process Hacker since everything is frozen. Could I somehow use the Windows performance analyzer, and if so, what metrics do I need to record/look at, and how would I set it up correctly?

I am using Windows 10 Version 22H2 (Build 19045.3393) atm but this problem has already plagued me for well over a year at least, if not two years. I have a ThinkPad T14s Gen1  (AMD) with an AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 4750U and 32 GB of RAM installed.

<sub>Note: I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/582653/why-one-page-can-make-whole-computer-freeze) but the answers don't match my symptoms. Overall CPU usage is at ~10% because I have 8 cores/16 threads, and a high-CPU-usage situation would also make the computer behave in a different way than that.</sub>

Comment: That ECMA page is ridiculous. It took about 2 minutes to load & ate an entire core whilst it did. It didn't slow the rest of my machine though, but I've 24 cores & 64GB RAM. Memory usage peaked at about 1GB, though it released some after i started scrolling down it - it's not attempting to hold is all in RAM at once & I see about 750MB of swap used, though I've still 33GB free RAM showing. GPU RAM went from 1GB to 2.2GB as it loaded initially, but has also backed off to about 1.5GB since it completed.

Comment: What you describe happening is kinda what I would expect to happen. The odd thing is that for me it hangs my whole system so badly that even the mouse cursor "jumps around" with updates only once per second even though only one CPU core is in use during that time. This _never_ happens for me in any other situation...

Comment: I occasionally see it when my ad-blocker gets over-zealous. The mouse cursor still moves OK, but the rest of the machine has stopped - including the clock - for maybe 10 seconds. I can disable the ad-blocker & this stops happening… but it's useful & I can't find another as good, so I have learned to live with it.

Comment: For me : This page opens pretty quick if JavaScript is disabled for it. If enabled, it keeps loading stuff for about 7 seconds. Chrome occupies about 550 MB memory when it all ends. Note: Slow internet requests *can* freeze Windows.

Comment: @harrymc - yup, much faster with javascript off & only about 350MB RAM… but it prevents me adding this comment;)